# <Python> OpenPIV Installation Error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, installation

I am attempting the installation of OpenPIV (python build) on 64-bit Win7.

Upon downloading the setup files(located - https://github.com/alexlib/openpiv-python) and running:

```
python setup.py install
```

I receive the error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Some research informed me to use:

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

Which then resulted in:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory.
```

So, I installed MinGW and adjusted the PATH variable to include `C:\MinGW\bin`, where `gcc.exe` is located, but no dice. Following this, I tried restarting my command prompt, restarting my computer, reinstalling MinGW, and reinstalling the setup files.

Running gcc:

```
C:\OpenPIV\> gcc
gcc:fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Which I assume means gcc works, but

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

still results in:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory.
```

Thanks everyone. Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you run `gcc` from command prompt now after adjusting the `PATH`?

Comment: @SukritKalra Yes, I can.

Comment: What error does it give now? Does it still say gcc not found?

Comment: @SukritKalra When I run gcc in prompt, it just says fatal error: no input files, which I assume means gcc works. When I try to setup again, I get the same error - error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory. I just looked into something about PYTHONPATH variable. Might you know where that's located or if I'm supposed to edit that as well?

Comment: Yes. Your gcc is working fine. I don't think you need to edit the PYTHONPATH environment variable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of searching, I've discovered that this is a problem between MinGW and Python. They don't communicate well with one another.

There exists a binary package of MinGW (unofficial) that was meant for use with Python located [here](http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries)

This fixes the problem!