# Error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, gcc, mingw, installation

I'm trying to run a

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

but it results in the error mentioned in the subject:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
```

but I am capable of running gcc from command prompt (i have added it to my PATH env var):

```
>gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit. Python27. Specific source I'm trying to build:

[OpenPIV](https://github.com/OpenPIV/openpiv-python)

[Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932383/python-openpiv-installation-error) on this issue.

Any help/advice/solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<Python> OpenPIV Installation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932383/python-openpiv-installation-error)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After hours and hours of searching, I've discovered that this is a problem between MinGW and Python. They don't communicate well with one another.

There exists a binary package of MinGW (unofficial) that was meant for use with Python located [here](https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries)

It fixes the problem!

Answer (score 16):

You need to install it first by using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sudo access, maybe try the following before installing the package:

```
conda install gcc gxx_linux-64
```