# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1, installing pymix

Tags: python, c++, gcc, mixture-model

I am in a terrible struggle to install pymix (Python27, Windows 7 32 bit).

I downloaded the version, however, I am unable to run setup.py as per the install directions.

First, my install resulted in a "unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error, which, per the 
directions of several people online, let me towards mingw32 as an installer. 
I followed the directions for ming32, added a path for a mingw32 install, 
and then received this error in the command prompt.

```
c:\Program Files\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pymix>setup.py build
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
The following include paths are used for compilation of the C extension:

Python.h: C:\Program Files\Python27/include/python2.7
arrayobject.h: C:\Program Files\Python27/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/numpy/core/
include/numpy

In case the installation fails, check these paths first.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
---

running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_C_mixextend' extension
C:\Program Files\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall "-IC:\Program 
Files\Python27/i
nclude/python2.7" "-IC:\Program Files\Python27/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/numpy
/core/include/numpy" "-IC:\Program Files\Python27\include" "-IC:\Program 
Files\P
ython27\PC" -c C_mixextend.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c_mixextend.o
gcc: C_mixextend.c: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Also, I followed some additional instructions  to 
download a binary package of MinGW (unofficial) that was meant for use with 
Python

[Error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972347/error-command-gcc-failed-no-)
such-file-or-directory

This didn't make any difference. Same error.

Lastly, pymix is the only module giving me any sort of errors. I have downloaded several others successfully

Thanks in advance for your time, and, seeing as its my first real go at 
Python, sorry if I wasn't clear!!

Answer (score 0):

You can download a precompiled version of `pymix` from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymix). You may also need to install [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) as well.

Comment: That's where I downloaded pymix from. Numpy was installed.  When I enter "import mixture" I get an error message, but "import numpy" works fine.

Comment: did you try `from pymix import mixture`?